# Aggregation mongodb grouping by a value

Tags: mongodb

I have the followings documents of a mongodb collection:

```
{
"year": 2020,
"cod": 4241,
"op": "12"
}

{
"year": 2021,
"cod": 2241,
"op": "34"
}

{
"year": 2020,
"cod": 4325,
"op": "54"
}

{
"year": 2021,
"cod": 1132,
"op": "A3"
}
```

I need an aggregator that let me group these documents by the year, in this way:

```
{
"year": 2020,
"values": [{"cod":4241, "op":"12"}, {"cod":4325, "op":"54"}]
}

{
"year": 2021,
"values": [{"cod":2241, "op":"34"}, {"cod":1132, "op":"A3"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$group: {
  _id: "$year",
  values: {
    $push: {
      cod: "$cod",
      op: "$op"
    }
  }
 }
},
{
 $project: {
  year: "$_id",
  values: 1,
  _id: 0
 }
}
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m-xc54ceRsK)